# Android: is it possible to add ZIP file as a raw resource and read it with ZipFile?

Tags: android, file, filesystems, zip

Is it possible to add ZIP file to APK package as a raw resource and read it with ZipFile class? It looks like it's trivial to open file from SD card, but not from APK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe so.  As you alluded, it's easy to use `ZipFile` with an actual file on the file system, but not so for a file embedded in your application.

For accessing a zip file in your APK, you'd have to use something like [`Resources.openRawResource(R.raw.zip_file)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29) and then wrap the returned `InputStream` in a `ZipInputStream` and do it the usual Java way, rather than with the Android method.

Alternatively, if you really find you need to use the `ZipFile` class, you could extract the zip file from the APK to the SD card or, more reliably, to your application's local storage.