# How to open a zip file and iterate through each compressed file on Android?

Tags: java, android, zip

I have a zip file in my `res/raw` directory. I want to open the zip file and iterate through the text files that are stored in it. I **do not** want to extract and write the files to the device; I just want to open the zip file, iterate through the lines in each text file, and then close the zip file.

I'm having trouble trying to read in the zip file because the `openRawResource` method returns an `InputStream`. I tried to convert the stream to a `ZipInputStream`, but I'm lost as to what to do next.

How do I create a `ZipFile` object in this case?

It's not much, but here's what I have so far:

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.primes);
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(in);
ZipEntry entry;
while ((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
  // TODO
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `ZipFile` with just a path and then put each entry into a `BufferedReader` using the `ZipInputStream` like this:

```
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("file_path");
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

    while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
        System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry)));
        String line;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    zipFile.close();
}
```

To get the file in res/raw you'll have to do something like this:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("myfile","raw", getPackageName()); //for res/raw/myfile.zip
```

Comment: In Android, would the file path be `/res/raw/file.zip` assuming that I put `file.zip` in the `/res/raw` directory?

Comment: dont' think it's that simple in android sadly: think this answer is what you'll need to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2017641/772385 , also some strange rules for file names as specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15934525/772385

Answer (score 1):

I found what I needed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13312005/739379). The person who answered the question recommended using the `read` method in `ZipInputStream` and reading the contents of the entries into a `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static void unzip(File zipFile) throws IOException {

    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
    ZipEntry ze;

    while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (!ze.isDirectory()) {                
            while (zin.read(buff) >= 0)
                // Do something with buff

        zis.closeEntry();
    }

    zis.close();
}
```